# C++ - Testing serial ports without a physical device

Tags: c++, serial-port, pty, virtual-serial-port

I have a program that splits a serial device into multiple virtual serial ports and routes all the data to them.

```
                    ---- /dev/ttyS1.a [data]->
                    |
[data]-> /dev/ttyS1 ---- /dev/ttyS1.b [data]->
                    |
                    ---- /dev/ttyS1.c [data]->
```

My working program (pseudo code for sake of readability and simplicity):

```
poll(...) {
    // Route data from master to vsp
    master.read(buf)
    for(virtual serial ports as vsp) {
        vsp.write(buf)
    }
    // Route data from vsp to master (if need be)
    for(virtual serial ports as vsp) {
        if(vsp.needs_to_write()) {
            vsp.read(buf)
            master.write(buf)
        }
    }
}
```

I have one physical serial port device on my machine that continuously feeds data through, which is how I tested if my program initially works, but I would like to write a test to emulate/simulate writing and reading both directions and verifying the data on both ends. Since the data I am receiving from my physical serial port device writes seemingly random data it is hard to verify what is going in is exactly what is being written.

How would I be able to do this? (pseudo code)

```
1. fork process that feeds a known char sequence into /dev/ttyS2 in a loop
2. use my program to read from the COM `master.read(buf)` and then write to the vsp `vsp.write(buf)`
3. how can I verify that after writing to the buf that the vsp has the correct data?
```

Any help is appreciated I am confused on how to automate testing this.

**Edit 1:**
No one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use com0com to test. You can connect virtual serial ports and then write to one and read from other what it received.
[enter link description here](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)